# Logo recognition in OpenCV

Tags: python, opencv

I am currently making an application with OpenCV and a web server that finds certain car brands as part of an ongoing game in my family.

However, I don't know where to start. I googled it but all I found was a post on finding a yellow ball. I want to find a car logo from a picture (which could be angled or glaring) so I identify the car brand and add points to the score.

I know it seems like a tall order but could anybody help?

Comment: This is so incredibly difficult to do that, without any demonstration of knowledge in the area I'm voting to close as too broad.

Comment: I second jedwards' comment. To accurately identify such a thing from a photo is very hard (read nearly impossible). Feature detection works on simple shapes that are in contrast with the rest of the image. That certainly isn't the case with car photos.

Answer (score 0):

You could probably use Haar cascades in openCv to do this. You will need to train haar detectors with both positive and negative samples of the logo but there is already utilities in openCv to help you with this. Just read up about haar in openCv documentation